# AWS - How to pause an Elastic Beanstalk environment without losing instance & elastic IP?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elastic-ip

So, I'm running an AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment with a single instance.

This particular app is a background job app, and in order to deploy changes to my database, I need to pause the app during the deployment process. I'm running into a couple of problems with this: -

- I can stop the EC2 instance for that EBS env, however this eventually terminates that instance, and it will spin up a new instance that immediately tries to run (don't want this, I want to control when the EBS env starts again).
- When the new instance starts up, the Elastic IP I've associated to the previous instance gets un-allocated, and is not automatically allocated to the new EC2 instance (this is a problem because my database has an IP firewall, so I need it to keep the same IP, before and after pausing).

I read that associating my EBS to an VPC might solve the IP issue, but I can't figure out how to do that. In my configuration it says "This environment is not part of a VPC.", but there isn't an option to make the environment part of a VPC?

Ideally, I'd love to just "pause" the instance, so that it stops and can be re-started without me losing that instance or the IP configuration of that instance.

Can anyone help me to solve these problems, or provide some other method of configuring this setup?

Comment: To help get better answers change your tag to [elastic-beanstalk]. Elastic Beanstalk is EB and not EBS (Elastic Block Store). Also use Beanstalk in the Title of your question.

Comment: What you are doing is breaking a design goal of Beanstalk. Beanstalk manages your environment. By stopping the instance, Beanstalk considers the EC2 instance failed and replaces it. Possible idea, move your database out of EB into RDS. However, you have not detailed why you need to stop your instance to make DB changes, RDS might not help either. You did not mention having a load balancer in EB. You could add one, assign the EIP to the load balancer. Remember you don't need to use EB. You can replace Beastalk with other AWS services that have finer grained control.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so experienced with Beanstalk, but you can use .ebsextension to get a script run at instance start, right? Then use that script to call aws api to get available Elastic IP and assign that to the instance itself.

Comment: Yeah that could potentially work. I'll look into that.

Any suggestions for dealing with the instance auto-starting after I stop it? I tried added Termination Protection and changing the stop behavior, but neither made a difference.